# ASP.NET Core : how can I get value from list as int?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list it give me result > id  but as a list.

I want this id as a int

This is the list

[image]

This is the result I need:

[image]

I want convert this result as int

Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Comment: Indeed, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

.First() will throw an exception when there are no results. Use FirstOrDefault() when you know that you will need to check whether there was an element or not.

According to your project logic, your return view will have one or no int number, so FirstOrDefault will be your best choice.

```
var EmpPC = _context.Employees
.Where(s=>s.EmployeeId == employee.TBEmployee.EmployeeId & s.PcId == employee.TBPc.PcId)
.Select(s=>s.EmpPcId)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Test

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks Brother This Workingggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work